# slot that have multiple parameters in QT

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qt-connection

I am in new Qt.I tryed that sinyal slot connection. But my slot function have three parameters. I used pressed button as sinyal. But connect function that i written is error.  How to pass multiple parameters to slots ?

```
connect(m_ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::released, m_fltrCnfgs, &SettingsFilter::show_parameters(10, "Port A", 0));
```

the error: cannot call member function 'void SettingsFilter::show_with_parameters(int, QString, bool)' without object

Comment: You'll probably want to use a lambda if you need to insert additional parameters